# Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Status_Collection::addStatusFilter()

Tags: php, magento

I use a finance payment module on my site which redirects the user after placing an order to the finance website to fill in their details.

I've just installed the 'One step checkout' from Magestore and testing the order cycle to make sure it worked like before, it doesn't.

After placing the order I get the error in the title

It's telling me there's an error on line 20 in StatusUpdate.php, below is the code for this file.

Can anyone tell me what's going on? [Screengrab of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eluVR.jpg)

```
<?php
class C3_V12Finance_Helper_StatusUpdate extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
public function handleOrderStatusUpdate(Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order, $configPath) {
    if ($status = Mage::getStoreConfig($configPath)) {
        $state = $this->getStateFromStatus($status);
        /* Magento doesn't allow some states to be changed manually ('complete' and 'closed'). This validation only
         * occurs however when you change state via setState. The validation doesn't occur on setData, however so
         * we use this as a workaround. */
        $order->setData('state', $state)
            ->setStatus($status)
            ->save();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public function getStateFromStatus($status) {
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_status_collection')
        ->addStatusFilter($status)
        ->joinStates();

    // Magento will actually prevent you from ever being able to have multiple statuses with the same code, but just to be safe...
    if ($collection->getSize() > 1) {
        Mage::throwException("Multiple statuses found with code " . $status . ". Ensure only one is present.");
    }

    $statusModel = $collection->getFirstItem();
    return $statusModel->getState();
}
}
```